# Tags in ARM file not visible in Azure portal

Tags: azure, tags, azure-resource-manager

I have multiple tags mentioned in my deployement yml file , but they are not visible inside Azure portal app service. None of the following tags visible to Azure portal. only cost-Center tag can be found.

```
 "resources": [
    {
          "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
          "comments": "",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
           "[variables('webAppDeployment')]"
          ],
          "kind": "app",
          "name": "[concat(parameters('siteName'),'/','staging')]",
          "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[parameters('appServicePlanResourceId')]"
          },
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "TEST",
            "Module": "MM",
            "SubModule": "ABD"
          }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To test this in our local environment, we have created a new ARM Template that will create an app service plan, web app & a staging slot to that web app with a list of tags that were shared above.

While testing the template, deployment got succeeded & we were able to see the tags of the webapp slot in the portal.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

**For reference , here is the sample ARM template that we have created to test this:**

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "web-appname": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "appservicename": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
 {
     "name": "[parameters('appservicename')]",
     "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
     "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
     "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
     "sku": {
         "name": "S1"
     },
     "properties": {
         "name": "[parameters('appservicename')]"
     }
 },
{
    "name": "[parameters('web-appname')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',parameters('appservicename'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('web-appname')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',parameters('appservicename'))]"
    }
},
{
    "name":"[concat(parameters('web-appname'),'/','stagging')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
    "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('web-appname'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "TEST",
            "Module": "MM",
            "SubModule": "ABD",
            "Createdfor": "repro",
            "depart":"test"
    },
    "properties": {
        "httpsOnly": true
    }
}
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I Will try with this code segment.